# How can I deselect all the selected divs when I drag or click an unselected div. But it has to not apply to a selected div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been coding this selection system that allows me to select widgets and drag a bunch of them, the problem is that when I select two widgets and I drag the other widget that's not selected, they're all being dragged, I don't want that to happen.

What is supposed to happen is that when I put my mouse down on a non-selected widget, all of the selected widgets have to not be selected anymore (that means the ".selected" class is removed). The problem is that I'm confused on how to apply this only to the non-selected widgets, it has to not apply to selected widgets.

**Here is the code before I tried:**

```js
let isSelecting = false;
let selectionStartX, selectionStartY, selectionEndX, selectionEndY;
let selectionRectangle;
let draggedElements = [];
const widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.widgets');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('widgets')) {
    draggedElements = Array.from(widgets).filter((widgets) => widgets.classList.contains('selected'));
    draggedElements.forEach((widgets) => {
      const shiftX = event.clientX - widgets.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const shiftY = event.clientY - widgets.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      function moveElement(event) {
        const x = event.clientX - shiftX;
        const y = event.clientY - shiftY;

        widgets.style.left = x + 'px';
        widgets.style.top = y + 'px';
      }

      function stopMoving() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
    });

    return;
  }

  isSelecting = true;
  selectionStartX = event.clientX;
  selectionStartY = event.clientY;
  selectionRectangle = document.createElement('div');
  selectionRectangle.id = 'selection-rectangle';
  selectionRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
  selectionRectangle.style.border = '2px dashed blue';
  selectionRectangle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  selectionRectangle.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(selectionRectangle);

  // Remove selected class from squares
  widgets.forEach((widgets) => {
    widgets.classList.remove('selected');
  });
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    selectionEndX = event.clientX;
    selectionEndY = event.clientY;

    let width = Math.abs(selectionEndX - selectionStartX);
    let height = Math.abs(selectionEndY - selectionStartY);

    selectionRectangle.style.width = width + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.height = height + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.left = Math.min(selectionEndX, selectionStartX) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.top = Math.min(selectionEndY, selectionStartY) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'block';

    widgets.forEach((widgets) => {
      const widgetsRect = widgets.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isIntersecting = isRectangleIntersecting(widgetsRect, {
        x: Math.min(selectionStartX, selectionEndX),
        y: Math.min(selectionStartY, selectionEndY),
        width,
        height,
      });
      if (isIntersecting) {
        widgets.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        widgets.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    isSelecting = false;
    selectionRectangle.remove();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('widgets') && event.target !== selectionRectangle) {
    // Remove selected class from squares
    squares.forEach((square) => {
      square.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }
});

function isRectangleIntersecting(rect1, rect2) {
  return (
    rect1.left >= rect2.x &&
    rect1.top >= rect2.y &&
    rect1.right <= rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.bottom <= rect2.y + rect2.height
  );
} // Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget3"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (elmnt.id + "header") {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#selection-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.widgets.selected {
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

#widget1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget1header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

#widget2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget2header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

#widget3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget3header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget1" class="widgets" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">
  <div id="widget1header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget2" class="widgets" style="left: 150px; top: 150px;">
  <div id="widget2header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget3" class="widgets" style="left: 250px; top: 250px;">
  <div id="widget3header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an if check on the `mousedown` event listener to see if the element on the `mousedown` is a selected element. If it is, move all selected elements, otherwise, remove the `selected` class from the elements.

```js
let isSelecting = false;
let selectionStartX, selectionStartY, selectionEndX, selectionEndY;
let selectionRectangle;
let draggedElements = [];
const widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.widgets');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('widgets')) {
    draggedElements = Array.from(widgets).filter((widgets) => widgets.classList.contains('selected'));
    
    const draggingSelected = event.target.matches('.selected') || event.target.closest('.selected');
    draggedElements.forEach((widgets) => {
      if (draggingSelected) {
        const shiftX = event.clientX - widgets.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        const shiftY = event.clientY - widgets.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        function moveElement(event) {
          const x = event.clientX - shiftX;
          const y = event.clientY - shiftY;

          widgets.style.left = x + 'px';
          widgets.style.top = y + 'px';
        }

        function stopMoving() {
          document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
          document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
        }

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
      } else {
        widgets.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });

    return;
  }

  isSelecting = true;
  selectionStartX = event.clientX;
  selectionStartY = event.clientY;
  selectionRectangle = document.createElement('div');
  selectionRectangle.id = 'selection-rectangle';
  selectionRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
  selectionRectangle.style.border = '2px dashed blue';
  selectionRectangle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  selectionRectangle.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(selectionRectangle);

  // Remove selected class from squares
  widgets.forEach((widgets) => {
    widgets.classList.remove('selected');
  });
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    selectionEndX = event.clientX;
    selectionEndY = event.clientY;

    let width = Math.abs(selectionEndX - selectionStartX);
    let height = Math.abs(selectionEndY - selectionStartY);

    selectionRectangle.style.width = width + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.height = height + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.left = Math.min(selectionEndX, selectionStartX) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.top = Math.min(selectionEndY, selectionStartY) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'block';

    widgets.forEach((widgets) => {
      const widgetsRect = widgets.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isIntersecting = isRectangleIntersecting(widgetsRect, {
        x: Math.min(selectionStartX, selectionEndX),
        y: Math.min(selectionStartY, selectionEndY),
        width,
        height,
      });
      if (isIntersecting) {
        widgets.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        widgets.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    isSelecting = false;
    selectionRectangle.remove();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('widgets') && event.target !== selectionRectangle) {
    // Remove selected class from squares
    squares.forEach((square) => {
      square.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }
});

function isRectangleIntersecting(rect1, rect2) {
  return (
    rect1.left >= rect2.x &&
    rect1.top >= rect2.y &&
    rect1.right <= rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.bottom <= rect2.y + rect2.height
  );
} // Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("widget3"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (elmnt.id + "header") {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#selection-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.widgets.selected {
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

#widget1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget1header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

#widget2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget2header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

#widget3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#widget3header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget1" class="widgets" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">
  <div id="widget1header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget2" class="widgets" style="left: 150px; top: 150px;">
  <div id="widget2header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
<div id="widget3" class="widgets" style="left: 250px; top: 250px;">
  <div id="widget3header" class="widgets"></div>
</div>
```